# Checking if UDP port is opened already in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

LANG: C

How can I check if the UDP socket is already opened so I can increment the used port and send on the next socket, I don't have any idea how much sockets the server will need.
I also can't use `port 0` as I have to start at a specific port.
Only solutions I have right now is either implement my own queue to trace open ports or try to read `/proc/net/udp`

Is there a defined API? also if no, can you submit a sample code that will trace opened ports used by my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the port is already in use bind will fail. If it fails you only need to increment the port you are trying to use. Then save it for when you want to use the next port. Bind returns -1 when fails. Btw, are you using linux?
You can stablish a max and a min port number and when the port you want to use reach the max, set port equal to min (this is the simplest method).
Other methods will need shared memory or semaphores and locks.

Comment: I already implemented this
    
`while (bind(sockfdstr, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof addr) <0 ){`
` port ++;`
` addr.sin_port = htons(port);`
` printf("Trying next port %d\n", port);`
`}`
but I used a different socket (TCP for another operations) so I got confused and thought it's not working